# Calling event.target.id for an a href tag with bold text in between

Tags: javascript, css

I am facing a weird issue. I have an a href tag

```
<a class="link" data-bind="click: templateToUse" href="#" id="InputType"><b>Title:</b> Content</a>
```

My JS

```
$('.link').click(function(event){
    if(event.target.id!='')
  alert(event.target.id);
    else
        alert('undefined');
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/ork50uf7/

Now if I click on the bold 'Title', it gives me an empty target Id. I assume that since the whole text is within the a href tag, it should send out the event target id, but incase we have a formatted text in the link, the formatted text wont send the correct event target.

Now, I am sure there is an easy fix for this. Maybe I am using CSS incorectly. I tried using the 'display:block' but this wont help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `currentTarget`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets) for an overview of the different "targets" in an event objects.

Solution:

```
if(event.currentTarget.id!='')
  alert(event.currentTarget.id);
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ork50uf7/2/).